# connecting sqlserver 2000 with php

Tags: php, sql-server, webserver

```
<?php   

    $serverName = "192.168.1.2";
    $connectionOptions = array('Database'=>'PKUSKH_2016', 'UID'=>'sa', 'PWD'=>'');

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
    if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Could not connect.\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    else {
        echo "koneksi berhasil..!";
        echo "Data item :";

        $tsql = "select KODEKELAS,NAMAKELAS from dbo.REF_";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
        {
          echo($row['KODEKELAS'] . ', '.
          $row['NAMAKELAS'].'<br>');
        }

        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: take at least 5mins to write a proper question so that people are motivated to help

Comment: Read the error message and it will tell you what's wrong. sqlserver2000 is too old for the odbc driver.

Comment: Okay, so that's a decent block of code, what's wrong with it? Care to add even a small amount of text to say what you are doing, what you expect to happen, and what is happening?

Comment: The best solution would be to upgrade to a version of sql server that is still supported. sql server 2000 has been out of support for close to a decade now. The two major version released AFTER sql 2000 are out of support which should give you an indication of far out of date your system is.

Comment: thank for answers. 
I try connect sql server with php version 1.7.7 can It.
but I try connect sql server with version up cann't it.